# List of Figures and Tables 1.5 and single spacing

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents

I am using the book document class to write a thesis, and am required to have the list of figures and tables as double spacing, but any table/figure title that spans two lines needs to be single spacing. I'm just using the `\listoftables` command, and spacing the document with

```
\usepackage{setspace}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
```

Right now this gives me

```
1.1    A shorter title .................... 1

1.2    A longer title that has to span more

       than one line ...................... 2
```

I need it to be:

```
1.1    A shorter title .................... 1

1.2    A longer title that has to span more
       than one line ...................... 2
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please always provide a small but compilable example document that can be used to reproduce the problem. You may want to have a look at the `locloft` package to increase the spacing between the ToC entries instead of changing the stretching for all text in the ToC.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cfttabafterpnum}{\\} % see the tocloft documentation
\usepackage{setspace}
%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\setstretch{1.5}

\begin{document}

\setstretch{1.0}
\listoftables
\setstretch{1.5}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}
\centering
A TABLE
\caption{A short captioned table}
\end{table}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{table}
\centering
ANOTHER TABLE
\caption{A table that has a caption much longer than the short captioned table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

BTW: use `\setstretch{...` instead of `renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{...`. It would also have helped if you had provided an MWE so we didn't have to waste time creating what your code might be.